# What is the French equivalent of The Chicago Manual of Style?

Tags: usage, orthographe, ressources, ponctuation, typographie

*The Chicago Manual of Style* is one of the oldest and most comprehensive English style guides. It's well-respected and widely used in the publishing industry, covering the areas of copy editing, grammar and typesetting.

What would be the closest equivalent for French? What about Canadian French?

Bonus points if you can offer some insider info on what other sources typographers and editors think highly of.

Also, what are some book, magazine or journal publishers that are known to pay special attention to good typography and typesetting?

Comment: Unquestionably [*Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_des_r%C3%A8gles_typographiques_en_usage_%C3%A0_l%27Imprimerie_nationale) is the editors' reference book and bible. Although it is by no means as heavy (number of pages and actual weight)  as the  CMS (922 pages for my 14th edition of the CMS to 196 pages last edition of the *Lexique*). This might be due to the fact that things are more clearcut and straightforward (rigid?) in French. The CMS contains a lot more examples as well.

Comment: For a good easily available online resource I recommend [this site](https://framasoft.org/article2225.html) and they give a couple of links at the end of the article.

Comment: For the exact equivalent of the CMS I expect you'd have to add up different books, because grammar and spelling are much more fixed in French and the *Lexique* doesn't cover those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say "Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale"

> what are some book, magazine or journal publishers that are known to
>   pay special attention to good typography and typesetting?

"Le journal officiel" or any official public document that is marked "cerfa" for "Centre d'enregistrement et de révision des formulaires administratifs"

Answer (score 3):

[Le bon usage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage), by [Maurice Grevisse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Grevisse) is a comprehensive resource for  teachers of French, authors, translators and editors.

J. André with [Petites leçons de typographie](http://jacques-andre.fr/faqtypo/lessons.pdf), offers a very useful booklet. 
[L'orthotypographie](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/) (typographical syntax) de J. Lacroux combines orthography and typography.

These are the main references I use on a regular basis.